# HTML tags in Rmarkdown to word document

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

Is there any possibility to use HTML tags in Rmarkdown documents rendered to word?

For example:

```
---
output: word_document
---

# This is rendered as heading

<h1> But this is not </h1>
```

Works perfectly when rendering as html_document, but not when rendering as a word_document.

A more specific question about  tags has been asked here, but without solution: [Underline in RMarkdown to Microsoft Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691866/underline-in-rmarkdown-to-microsoft-word)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this is not possible by simply using HTML tags. The reason why HTML tags work when rendering to HTML is that the HTML code is not touched upon by rmarkdown, knitr or pandoc and simply passed through to the final HTML document as text. In case of HTML the browser knows what to do with this "text". But in Word or Latex it's simply text which will be displayed as is. If your final goal is word output only then have a look at the `officedown` package which adds some addtional word functionality to rmarkdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, here we go:

```
---
output:
  word_document:
    md_extensions: +raw_html-markdown_in_html_blocks
    pandoc_args: ['--lua-filter', 'read_html.lua']
---

# This is rendered as heading

<h1> And this is one, too </h1>
```

where `read_html.lua` must be a file in the same directory with this content:

```lua
function RawBlock (raw)
  if raw.format:match 'html' and not FORMAT:match 'html' then
    return pandoc.read(raw.text, raw.format).blocks
  end
end
```

Let's unpack the above to see how it works. The first thing you'll notice are the additional parameters to `word_document`. The `md_extensions` modify the way that pandoc parses the text, see [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#pandocs-markdown) for a full list (or run `pandoc --list-extensions=markdown`) in your terminal. We enable `raw_html` to make sure that pandoc does not discard raw HTML tags, and disable `markdown_in_html_blocks` as to ensure that we get the whole HTML tag as one block in pandoc's internal format.

The next setting is `pandoc_args`, where we tell pandoc to use a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to modify the document during conversion. The filter picks out all HTML blocks, parses them as HTML instead of Markdown, and replaces the raw HTML with the parsing result.

So if you are using raw HTML that pandoc can read, you'll be fine. If you are using special instructions which pandoc cannot read, then the setup described above won't help either. You'd have to rewrite the markup in OOXML, the XML format used in docx.